# How do I equalize the spacing between each element in the bottom navigation bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
          child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: selectedIndex,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              items:  const [

                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: Icon(IconlyBold.home),
                    icon: Icon( IconlyLight.home),
                    label: 'Home'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: Icon(IconlyBold.bookmark),
                    icon: Icon(IconlyLight.bookmark),
                    label: 'Courses'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: Icon(IconlyBold.document),
                    icon: Icon(IconlyLight.document),
                    label: 'My Learning'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    activeIcon: Icon(IconlyBold.profile),
                    icon: Icon(IconlyLight.profile),
                    label: 'Profile'),
              ]),
        ),
        backgroundColor: creamwhite,
        body: SnackbarWidget(
          child: Center(
            child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
          ),
        ));
```

[image: Bottom Navigation Bar]

As seen in the image, the space between the first item and the second item is too much, but the gap between the others is normal. How do I equalize the spaces between all items?

Comment: Ty providing a padding around Icons,  `EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: "some value"
                      horizontal: "some value",
                    )` or try removing labels to check if this happens based on label length

Comment: When I pad the icons, the labels stay in place and do not move.